# Image in collapsing toolbar doesn't fill the whole AppBar layout on all mobile screens

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've used two screen mobile to test my app . The item inside collapsing toolbar layout works fine for the smaller screen device but it cuts from bottom when using larger device . NOTE:-TAB COLOR IS done RED MANUALLY . NO CODE ISSUE THERE .

[image: as can be seen that the single items of collapsing toolbar here fills the parent as i've used match_parent and height . The device that is used to display is a smaller screen device .]

[image: as can be seen that the single items of collapsing toolbar here do not fills the parent .Here the textview cuts from bottome. The device that is used to display is a larger screen device .]

the code for the single items of collapsing toolbar is as follow,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/recyclervire_back"
android:weightSum="4"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3">

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"

    android:id="@+id/hori_item_image"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textColor="#00b704"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/hori_item_source"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:textSize="8sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Loading ..."
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/hori_item_title"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Now the main layout where the collapsing toolbar is written is as follow,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context="com.sixteenmb.abhishekint.stack.MainActivity"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:id="@+id/main_coordinator">

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="180dp"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:id="@+id/main_appbarlayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="left"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@color/white"
        app:contentScrim="@color/toolbar_main_activity"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="40dp"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/main_recyclerview"
            android:background="@color/white">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
          android:fadeScrollbars="false"
          android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          android:id="@+id/main_nested">
      <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

           <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="35dp"
                   app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                   android:background="#6e000000"
                   app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                   app:tabIndicatorHeight="1.5dp"
                   android:id="@+id/tab">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/main_pager">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the receycler view in collapsing toolbar is where i inflate these items . 
can anyone suggest where am i going wrong?
**Actually setting wrap_content and fitsSystemWindow=true in both AppBarlayout and recyclerview and then setting the desired item layout height to the parent linear layout of the recycler item worked for me . in my case I set 180dp**

Comment: set wrap_content to appbar layout

Comment: @DivyeshPatel still not working

Comment: then set recyelrview height wrap and add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to it

Comment: @DivyeshPatel not working . I tried with keeping appbarlayout match_parent , wrap_content and then combine it with setting match_parent, wrap_content to recycler view with and without fitssystemwindow=true . not working

Comment: did you try with setting recycler item height to wrap?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel yes i tried .not working

Comment: is both device running on different version?

Comment: @DivyeshPatel YES . smaller screen that is showing the red tab is android version 4.2 . And the larger screen device that cuts the content from bottom is android version 5.1

Comment: Then I think you are getting warning at  android:elevation="10dp", try to remove that and check again

Comment: Actually setting wrap_content and fitsSystemWindow=true in both AppBarlayout and recyclerview and then setting the desired item layout height to the parent linear layout of the recycler item worked for me . in my case I set 180dp .

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I'm still getting one problem . By setting wrap_content to both , the layout fits and the texts don't cut from bottom but now the image cuts from above in the android version 5.1 and it works fine for the other

Comment: for that remove fitsystemwindow from layout

Comment: @DivyeshPatel it seems to play some game . Now after removing fitssystemwindow from recycler view . Image is shown fine but again the texts getting cut from bottom .

Comment: removing fitssystemwindow from appbatlayout and retaining it for recyclevriew worked ffor me. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146725/discussion-between-abhishek-kumar-and-divyesh-patel).